# Testing Dropwizard Post method for URL resource

Tags: unit-testing, post, dropwizard, http-status-code-405

I have a url resource that has a GET and a POST method. To test the GET method I followed this article https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/docs/source/manual/testing.rst
But is there  a way to test the POST method? Also I am using iceweasel on Debian and would like to know if there is a 'POSTMAN'(chrome) like plugin that can be used to test url resources??

Comment: If you have two different questions, then post two different questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following for the entity:

```
Entity<?> entity = Entity.entity(person, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);    
final Response response = RESOURCES.target("/person/blah")
                    .request()
                    .post(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same technique as `GET` - just switch to `POST`:

```java
@Test
public void testPostPerson() {
  assertThat(resources.client().target("/person/blah")
     .request().post(Person.class)).isEqualTo(expectedResponse);
  verify(dao).createPerson("blah");
}
```

On linux I often find it useful to just use `curl` from the command line for testing REST resources. See:

- [The curl man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)
- [A curl POST example](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request)

Comment: That gives me an error The method post(Entity<?>) in the type SyncInvoker is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Person>)?